# i18n c# mvc alternate ways

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my application I am trying to introduce internationalization. After searching on internet I have got some really vague ideas on how to do that. One being using the resource files. I found some git hub projects as well but not sure how good they are.

I am pretty sure a lot of people must have encountered this. Is there a best option? Or it depends on something?

Looking forward for suggestions.

Comment: This great post from Scott Hanselman should answer all of your questions: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx